# How to make ReactJS JSX's work on electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I've wanted to create simple desktop app which uses React JS for data presentation.

However, I'm overwhelmed with so many modules and technologies. There is an [electron react boilerplate](https://github.com/thangngoc89/electron-react-app) which very complicated for starters like me.

I have simple project with these libs:

1. `electron` as dev
2. `react`
3. `react-dom`

I have `main.js` in my root path of my project which launches electron and it is taken from [this quickstart example](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start)

I have `index.html` file where my JSX should be loaded:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="react-view"></div>
  </body>

  <script type="text/jsx">
    // You can also require other files to run in this process
    require('./scripts/application');
  </script>
</html>
```

There are `scripts/application.js` file where my JSX will be populated to my `<div id="react-view"></div>`.

My `App.jsx` is very simple:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class App extends Component{
    render() {
        return <h1>Hello From React</h1>;
    }
}

export default App;
```

My `application.js` file looks like this:

```
import React    from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom/server';
import App      from 'components/App';

ReactDom.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("react-view"));
```

When I launch my electron application it opens me a window with empty content, which means that my JSX is not loaded. **And it does not throw any error messages**

What did I miss?

Comment: Any specific reason you are using "react-dom/server"? That seems different to me. I just use react-dom. Also, are you using anything like webpack to bundle the react app. import is not supported by the browser directly and needs to be transpiled using Babel.

Comment: @shashi I've just read some article and tried to use its code. I don't use webpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem - **no one understands JSX except a transpiler**.

Two ways, you can get JSX work -

1. use a browser based/client side transpiler (use only for development
   purpose)

   - include this file as a script tag

     `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.js"></script>`
   - use `type="text/babel"` on your script tag which loads your JSX

     `<script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>`

checkout the sample here - https://github.com/rabibiswal/reactdemo/tree/master/hello-world-jsx

2. user a server based transpiler - e.g. Babel

You can use different tools like webpack etc.

checkout the sample here - 
https://github.com/rabibiswal/reactdemo/tree/master/hello-world-react-es5

You need to install node and use `npm install` and `npm run build` to get this code working